# Mongoose, getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting the error, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')` which points to the block of code:

```
app.get('/Organizations', (req,res) => {
Organizations.find({}).then((organization) => {
    res.send(organization);
}); })
```

app.js, importing mongoose schema:

```
const {Organizations} = require('./db/models');
```

Organization.model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrganizationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    organizationName:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength:1,
        trim: true
    }
})

    
const Organizations = mongoose.model( 'Organizations', OrganizationsSchema);

module.exports =  (Organizations)
```

index.js:

```
const { Organizations } = require('./Organizations.model');
module.exports = {
    Organizations
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an import/export problem. In `Organization.model.js` you used parentheses instead of curly braces when exporting `Organisations`. Export it like so:

```
module.exports =  {Organizations}
```

And import it this way:

```
const { Organizations } = require('./Organizations.model');
```